# Difference in HTTP streaming

Tags: http, streaming

I know what differs HLS from rtsp but I'm confused with basic http streaming. I tried to google but I found contrary information. F.e. on this page http://wesstreamingcontent.wordpress.com/technology/how-video-streaming-works/ in the video, which is on the bottom, this guy is talking that in HTTP streaming you can't jump in video till it's not fully downloaded. However here are some samples http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/http-mp4.htm and I can do that the same as in rtsp. So what is exactly http streaming and are there different variations of it?